# Change in min/max values after Interpolation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation

After rasterizing my shapefile with IWD Interpolation scheme, **the min/max values change depending upon the distance coefficient and rows/columns values I choose**, should I change the values in interpolated layer to the original min/max or would the new values generalize the original content and hence the output graph would be same?

What distance coefficient should be optimal if I need to point on exact locations in graph, how should one set the values for rows/columns (what should be their optimal range)?